# can someone please break down 4th line of code for me? This is in R

Tags: r

```
r=5  # 5 blocks
t=10 # 10 treatments
RCB=matrix(0, r, t)
for(i in 1:r)RCB[i,]=sample(1:t)
#rownames(RCB)=c("Block","Treatment")
data.frame(RCB)
```

can someone please break down the 4th line of code for me? This is in R. The author is trying to create an RCBD data set, I didn't write this code. I'm trying to learn for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my explanation of the fourth line.

- `for(i in 1:r)` This specifies a for loop that iterates from 1 to `r`. In this example, `r` is `5`. `:` is a way to specify a sequence from one integer to another, so `1:r` is the same as `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.
- `RCB[i, ]` means for each iteration, access to row `i` in the matrix. There are five rows in `RCB`. The for loop will access to each row one by one.
- `=` is the assign operator in R. We can also use `<-`.
- `sample(1:t)` takes a random sample from `1:t`. In this example, it is one number from `1` to `10`. The output would store to that row in `RCB`.

Before you run line 4, the `RCB` matrix is as follows.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

After line 4, it becomes something like this.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    5    7    6    8    2    1    9    3   10     4
[2,]    5    3    2    8    9    4    7    1    6    10
[3,]    6    9   10    3    8    1    7    5    4     2
[4,]    2    1    5    9    4    3   10    7    6     8
[5,]    4    6    5    3   10    1    9    8    7     2
```

All rows are populated with random numbers from `1` to `10`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand this now